files.getUploadURLExternal in Slack return's a null URL
Im trying to upload images to our organization's slack channel. The bot has all the permissions, the token is correct.
But this is the response I get:
{"ok":true,"url":null,"file_id":"F0811DJ16GG"}

Somehow, the URL is null, and i was supposed to use it to upload, isn't that right?
This is the code I use
  string url = "https://slack.com/api/files.getUploadURLExternal";

        Debug.Log("S: " + SlackApiToken);
    
        var urlEncoded = "filename=" + fileName + "&length=" + textureSize;
        
        url += "?" + urlEncoded;
        Debug.Log("URL: " + url);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + SlackApiToken);
            www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ...

read the documentation and searched for the issue
